# Bcrypt password encoding doesnt matches the input password in springBoot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using springsecurity bcrypt password encoder for encoding my password this is how I am saving my password

```
public User saveUser(User newUser) {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        String encode = bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(newUser.getPassword());
        newUser.setPassword(encode);
        User user = userRepo.save(newUser);
        return user;

    }
```

And this is how I defined a bean

```
@Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        
    }
```

but when I am trying to match the password with the encoded password I am not able to sign in .I have used passwordencoder.matches but its not helping

```
  public Response login(String username, String password) throws Exception {
            BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
            Response response = new Response();
            Optional<User> byuser_nameAndPassword = userRepo.getByuser_nameAndPassword(username);
            User user = byuser_nameAndPassword.get();
            String encodedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(password);
            boolean matches = passwordEncoder.matches(encodedPassword, user.getPassword());
            if (matches){
                response.setStatus(201);
                response.setMessage("Login Succeeded");
            } else {
                response.setStatus(403);
                response.setMessage("You are not Authorized");
            }
    
            return response;
        }
    
    }
```

Any help is appreciated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the parameters in the incorrect format to `boolean matches = passwordEncoder.matches(encodedPassword, user.getPassword());`

The [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCryptPasswordEncoder.html) says:

> boolean   matches​(java.lang.CharSequence rawPassword, java.lang.String encodedPassword)

The first parameter must be the raw password, not the encoded one.

It should be:

```java
boolean matches = passwordEncoder.matches(password, user.getPassword())
```